# Pagination for a generic search in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a million records in my database. I want to implement a generic search box with regex and  the results should appear 50 per page . I want to implement pagination

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def query
    @tweets =Tweets.where("%query%=?", params[:search]).all
  end
end
<%= form_tag({controller: "tweets", action:"query" }, method: "get") do  %>
<%= label_tag(:search, "search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:search) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

its actually a full text search. .For eg if  i enter "apple"  it should show results starting, ending, starting also anywer in d middle ,and it should show all the columns in the table.Any one Please help me . Thks in advance.

Comment: use kaminari. Its a good option. See my answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have Tweet model as per your controller says TweetsController .

Use pagination for will_paginate(https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

And in controller change a little bit like

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def query

    @tweets = Tweet.where("field LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%" ).paginate(
      page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
  end
end
```

In views

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
```

Comment: can u pls help me with dis. it works fine but its not displaying the full text which is one of the column which cantains  the query word. my output should display the full-text  of that column. for eg if i type "sheep" it should display all the matching columns in the table and the full text in the tweet_text column which s not happening.pls pls help me  . Iam stuck up with dis

Answer (score 0):

You can use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) gem.

To do this, you first add

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

to your `Gemfile`, then you run `bundle`. When you are done, you type in your controller:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def query
    @tweets = Tweets.where("%query%=?", params[:search]).paginate(
      page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
  end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
```

to display pages links.

Comment: thks every one it works fine but its not displaying one column called "tweet_text" which cantains the search word , my output should display the full text of this column but its not displaying . anyone pls help me. I tried find_by_sql but its not working in combination with paginate. any1 kindly help me in dis. thks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Another good option is using [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) Gem

```
 def index
   @tweets = Tweet.where("%query%=?",params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @tweets }
  end
end
```

You can simply configure **default_per_page** as you needed. Please read [Configuring Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#general-configuration-options)

And in views simply use

```
 <%= paginate @tweets %>
```

Comment: thks every one it works fine but its not displaying one column called "tweet_text" which cantains the search word , my output should display the full text of this column but its not displaying . anyone pls help me. I tried find_by_sql but its not working in combination with paginate. any1 kindly help me in dis. thks in advance

Comment: i didn't get u. Please post Tweet model in question.